# why Spring Security firewall rejects WebDav methods like "PROPFIND"?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, webdav, milton

I've written a project by spring boot, now I'm using [Milton Project](https://milton.io/) to add webdav support.
there is some simple [example](https://github.com/HFakhraei/spring-boot-samples/tree/master/spring-boot-milton) that works well.
but when I add this example to my project, Spring Security Firewall rejects requests.

thank you in advance for your answers.

pom

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>io.milton</groupId>
        <artifactId>milton-server-ce</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

filter configuration

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource({"classpath*:applicationContext.xml"})
public class SpringBeanConfig {
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<SpringMiltonFilter> someFilterRegistration() {
        FilterRegistrationBean<SpringMiltonFilter> registration = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
        registration.setFilter(new SpringMiltonFilter());
        registration.addUrlPatterns("/webdav/*");
        registration.setOrder(0);
        return registration;
    }
}
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="resource.factory" class="io.milton.http.annotated.AnnotationResourceFactory">
    <property name="controllers">
        <list>
            <bean class="webdav.controllers.WebDavController" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean class="io.milton.http.fs.NullSecurityManager" id="nullSecurityManager"/>

<bean id="milton.http.manager" class="io.milton.config.HttpManagerBuilder">
    <property name="mainResourceFactory" ref="resource.factory" />
    <property name="enableCompression" value="false"/>
    <property name="buffering" value="never"/>
    <property name="contextPath" value="/webdav/"/>
    <property name="securityManager" ref="nullSecurityManager"/>
</bean>
```

and finally the exception

```
org.springframework.security.web.firewall.RequestRejectedException: The request was rejected because the HTTP method "PROPFIND" was not included within the whitelist [HEAD, DELETE, POST, GET, OPTIONS, PATCH, PUT]
at org.springframework.security.web.firewall.StrictHttpFirewall.rejectForbiddenHttpMethod(StrictHttpFirewall.java:360) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.firewall.StrictHttpFirewall.getFirewalledRequest(StrictHttpFirewall.java:335) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:194) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1579) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar:9.0.27]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because of the StrictHTTPFirewall, introduced in Spring 5.1. It only allows some HTTP verbs per default:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/firewall/StrictHttpFirewall.html#setAllowedHttpMethods-java.util.Collection-

You can manually add the verbs for WebDAV, examples are here:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/5377#issuecomment-391738069

Comment: Is the PROPFIND request called automatically in springboot or who invokes it ?

Comment: the webdav client connecting to Spring/Milton invokes it.